# Generate migration on app start - code first

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

In my dev environment I wish my database would update automatically to match the updated code first model on each application start.
This must obviously not be the case in my production environment but I wish to at least try setting this up in local.

At this point I have setup "auto migration" but for this to work I have to execute `update-database` manually in the NuGet console.
I wish this command could be executed automatically on every call of `Application_Start()`

Is this possible ? If not, why ? If it is, how can i implement it ?

Comment: `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` class can be used in this context. It is not recommended in production database.

Comment: I have tried using `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`, but it doesn't seem to generate a new migration when the model was updated. I may have improperly done something, I will try again

Comment: Why downvote this ?

Comment: its a perfectly good question, one that makes sense if you have a continuous deployment system and don't want to manually connect to your live DB and run commands after every release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use that :

```
new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, MyConfiguration>().InitializeDatabase(Db);
```

in Controller constructor where `MyConfiguration` is :

```
internal sealed class MyConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MigrationDbContext>
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

}
```